# Numpy: use dtype from genfromtxt() when exporting with savetxt()

Tags: python, numpy

`numpy.genfromtxt(infile, dtype=None)` does a pretty good job of determining the number formats in each column of my input files. How can we use those same already determined types when saving the data file with `numpy.savetxt()`? Savetxt uses a very different format syntax.

```
indata = '''
    1000  254092.500 1630087.500  9144.00  9358.96   214.96
     422  258667.500 1633267.500  6096.00  6490.28   394.28
      15  318337.500 1594192.500  9144.00 10524.28  1380.28
     -15  317392.500 1597987.500  6096.00  4081.26 -2014.74
     -14  253627.500 1601047.500 21336.00 20127.51 -1208.49
END
'''
```

code

```
import numpy as np
header = 'Scaled_Residual,X,Y,Local_Std_Error,Vertical_Std_Error,Unscaled_Residual'
data = np.genfromtxt(indata, names=header, dtype=None,
    comments='E') #skip 'END' lines

print data.dtype
```

emits:

```
[('Scaled_Residual', '<i4'), ('X', '<f8'), ('Y', '<f8'), ('Local_Std_Error', '<f8'), ('Vertical_Std_Error', '<f8'), ('Unscaled_Residual', '<f8')]
```

so how to elegantly reconstruct `data.dtype` so that it fits `savetxt(... fmt='%i, %f, ...'` syntax without manually stepping through it? Is there an *savefromgentxt()* corollary I haven't discovered?

A simplistic, hopeful attempt at `fmt=data.dtype` fails completely. ;-)

```
np.savetxt('test.csv', data, header=header, delimiter=',',
    fmt=data.dtype)
```

Result:

```
  ...snip...\numpy\lib\npyio.py", line 1047, in savetxt
    fh.write(asbytes(format % tuple(row) + newline))
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'format' referenced before assignment
```

Comment: Part of the problem is that there is no unambiguous way to go from a dtype to a format string. For example, the text file comes with information on spacing and alignment of columns, and a specific number of decimal places for floating-point numbers. That information is completely lost by the dtype (as it should be!).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fmt` is supposed to a format string, or list of strings.  See the examples in `savetxt` documentation.  It is not a `dtype`.

```
np.savetxt('test.csv',data, fmt='%10s')
```

gets 90% of the way there:

```
  1000   254092.5  1630087.5     9144.0    9358.96     214.96
   422   258667.5  1633267.5     6096.0    6490.28     394.28
    15   318337.5  1594192.5     9144.0   10524.28    1380.28
   -15   317392.5  1597987.5     6096.0    4081.26   -2014.74
   -14   253627.5  1601047.5    21336.0   20127.51   -1208.49
```

You would get closer by specifying a fmt string with number of decimals etc for each column.

```
np.savetxt('test.csv',data, fmt='%10d  %10.3f %10.3f %10.2f %10.2f %10.2f')
```

does better.  You can tweak the `fmt` further.

The Python code for `savetxt` is not that complex.  I'd suggest looking at it.

The problem with generating anything fancier from the `dtype` is that there isn't much more information.

```
In [154]: [x[1] for x in data.dtype.descr]
Out[154]: ['<i4', '<f8', '<f8', '<f8', '<f8', '<f8']
```

Compare these formats:

```
In [158]: '%i %f %f %f %f %f'%tuple(data[0])
Out[158]: '1000 254092.500000 1630087.500000 9144.000000 9358.960000 214.960000'

In [159]: '%s %s %s %s %s %s'%tuple(data[0])
Out[159]: '1000 254092.5 1630087.5 9144.0 9358.96 214.96'

In [160]: ' '.join(['%10s']*6)%tuple(data[0])
Out[160]: '      1000   254092.5  1630087.5     9144.0    9358.96     214.96'
```

A simple translation of the `dtype` info:

```
def foo(astr):
    if 'i' in astr:
        return '%10i'
    elif 'f' in astr:
        return '%10f'
[foo(x[1]) for x in data.dtype.descr]
# ['%10i', '%10f', '%10f', '%10f', '%10f', '%10f']
```

You could also use the `dtype` names to generate a header line.

Comment: The thrust of the question (is supposed to be) how to use the information already present in `dtype` to feed `fmt`. It's trying to avoid the work of hard coding the format strings, to derive them dynamically from the input. I guess I didn't express that well!

Comment: Sorry, I was focusing on the final error message, not earlier `savetxt(... fmt='%i, %f, ...'`.  But doesn't `%s` do just as well?